# Draft.js editor still shows updates even when the onChange function is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I am currently working with Draft.js and I have encountered an unexpected behavior. Despite the onChange function not working, the Draft.js editor continues to display updates in its content. I have created a CodeSandbox demo to illustrate this issue: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/draft-js-running-without-even-on-change-running-5d6phb?file=/src/App.tsx)

In the provided demo, you can observe that changes made to the editor are reflected in its displayed content, even though the onChange function does not trigger and the state remains unchanged. This behavior is confusing to me, as I would expect the editor to update its state only when the onChange function is called.

I am seeking guidance to understand why the Draft.js editor is still able to show updates despite the onChange function not working properly. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: See if simply calling the onChange function provided by the Editor component without additional conditions helps